# I want to add an image uploader same like already exist in catalog/category/index/ name homepage image in same page

Tags: magento2, admin, category, catalog, image-upload

I want to create a image uploader on catalog/category/index/ just like homepage image which is on catalog/category/index/ page

[image: already exist image uploader on catalog/category/index]

Now I am using this to create same above but not success

InstallData.php

eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'category_child_image',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Category Child Image',
                'name'         => 'Category Child Image',
                'input'        => 'image',
                'backend'      => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'group' => 'General Information'
            ]            
        );
    }
}

category_form.xml


    
        
            
                
                    false
                    
                        false
                    
Iversa_StaticCategoryImage/form/element/custom-button
                    category_child_image
                    
                        category_child_image
                        file
                     -->

```
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Category Child Image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

custom-button.html

Select from Gallery

and I got this
[image: result of code]
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file "`UpgradeData.php`"

```
UpgradeData - this class will run when the module is upgraded to add/remove data from table.
```

will be located at `app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup` folder. The module install/upgrade script will run when you run the following command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Make sure to upgrade module version to higher then the current

& use this in upgrade script

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0', '<'))
```

Take a look at other upgrade.php to get more idea about its code.